# How to JWT Authorization in Angular 2.0

Tags: angular, authentication, authorization, jwt

I want to implement JWT Authorization for Angular 2.0 route and use as directive for show/hide some section of page view like this [ngAA](https://github.com/lykmapipo/ngAA) plugins.

Do you have any suggestion or plugins for do that?

Comment: The Angular2 way may be guards to the router, see this [official documentation](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html#!#guards).

Answer (score 3):

A few things that you’ll need:

- an authentication service that’ll allow to login, logout and check whether you’re authenticated (so that you’ll be able to use eg. `*ngIf="auth.isLogged()"`),
- an authentication guard that you’ll attach to protected routes in router configuration,
- a login component/dialog and something similar to logout,
- a way to automatically append `Authorization` header to protected API calls.

Try [angular2-jwt](https://github.com/auth0/angular2-jwt) library, it provides `AuthHttp` wrapper over Angular’s `Http` service which solves the last problem. And it may be helpful to read the following guides:

- [“Angular authentication revisited” by blacksonic86](https://medium.com/@blacksonic86/angular-2-authentication-revisited-611bf7373bf9)
- [“Easy Angular Authentication with JSON Web Tokens” on Angular blog](https://angularjs.blogspot.com/2016/11/easy-angular-authentication-with-json.html), consider it a guide on angular2-jwt usage

Answer (score 0):

you can use [ng-jwt](https://github.com/mo3in/ng-jwt) library for angular +2